# Can anyone help look into my scrapy xpath for this site?

Tags: scrapy

When I tried to scrape pissedconsumer.com item with following code:

```
import scrapy

class PissedreviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'pissedreviews'
    allowed_domains = ['pissedconsumer.com']
    start_urls = ['https://lazada-malaysia.pissedconsumer.com/review.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        selectors = response.xpath('//div[@class="f-component-info"]')
        for selector in selectors:
            title = selector.xpath('./h2/text()').get()
            print(title)
```

Here is the log in shell when crawl:

```
2020-04-11 19:00:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://lazada-malaysia.pissedconsumer.com/review.html> (referer: None) <Selector xpath='//div[@class="f-component-info"]' data='<div class="f component-info">\n      ...'>
None
<Selector xpath='//div[@class="f-component-info"]' data='<div class="f-component-info">\n      ...'>
```

I already set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY to false and added headers

Any other things I can do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Please share more information with us. What do you mean with "No data returned for response"? Is it None? What happening when you use xpath?

Comment: Hi, I have update my thread, it seems my xpath error. But when I test it in xpath helper it shows correctly the block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update because question updated:**

You are missing a / in your xpath. It should be `title = selector.xpath('.//h2/text()').get()`

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried your code, it is working on my end. Seems it's my xpath issue. I'm trying  to figure it out now.

Comment: @LoganYu updated my answer to match your updated question and code.